# Laravel How to get multi different results by executing only one query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-collection

Laravel version :7.0

```
$posts = Post::where("status", 1)->get();
```

Above returns all approved posts.

```
$top_featured_posts = Post::where("status", 1)->orderBy("featured", "DESC")->take(4);
```

Above will get 4 posts order by featured.

```
$top_recent_posts = Post::where("status", 1)->latest()->take(4);
```

Above will get 4 posts order by created_at.
...

How can I get them with only one query?

I want to get results as following to use them.

```
$top_featured_posts[0], $top_featured_posts[1], $top_featured_posts[2], $top_featured_posts[3]  

$top_recent_posts[0], $top_recent_posts[1], $top_recent_posts[2], $top_recent_posts[3]
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this:

```
$posts = Post::where("status", 1)->get();

$top_featured_posts = $posts->sortByDesc("featured", "DESC")->take(4)->values();

$top_recent_posts = $posts->sortByDesc("created_at")->take(4)->values();
```

---

Documentation
[Laravel Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.`

Comment: Try sortBy if orderBy is not working in your larave 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby

if you still get error post your controller code

Comment: @THCBin looks at my comment.